# Texmaker - Mactex - MacOs Sierra weird problems

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, mac

it's my first post and will be so happy to have an answer from one of you.

One of my friend is doing her Master thesis on latex using texmaker, mactex and her macbook air on MacOs Sierra (10.12.5)

To install everything properly we followed this tutorial: https://www.um.edu.mt/__data/assets/pdf_file/0004/171373/LaTeX_Tutorial.pdf

So now here is the problem. When using files that works fine on my windows computer we always got this log file error:

> !Undefined control sequence.
>    \ifnum \pdfshellescape
>   0 \edef \Gin@extensions {\Gin@extensions ...
>   l.195 \begin{document}
>   The control sequence at the end of the top line
>   of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
>   misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct
>   spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
>   and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>   ! Missing number, treated as zero.
>
> l.195 \begin{document}
>   A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number, look up`weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.) Package mathastext Info: current meaning of amsmath \resetMathstrut@ saved on input line 195.

To give you extra information; we compile on texmaker by doing pdflatex+Pdfview for this file.

We dont find any solution on the internet about this kind of problem.. Even on your great forum. I can give you the whole log if you want or  the whole latex folder.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That tutorial is very much out of date. Plus we'd like to see what ever sample document it is you are trying to compile here. This might be a better starting point: https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But there is no installation tutorial for mac on the website you gave me.. How can i give you the whole .tex file ?

Comment: On a Mac, use MacTeX, see tug.org/mactex, it is the easiest LaTeX installation to install over all platforms. You can post your code here (in an update to your question).

Comment: For clarity your problem is that a file does not visibly report errors on windows whilst on a similar Mac configuration it does show errors. So the questions to be asked in return are  is it the same revision MiKTeX on Mac & Win are they both stable at EXACTLY the same revision (recommend at same user level) NOT DUAL admin and user 2x 2 x 2!= exponential times the trouble. often such 2 user mismatched issues disappear when both users sync their updates. To provide a suitable file we need a heavily trim down version from the mac exhibiting such behaviour (Minimum Working Error) and log

Comment: To try and track down similar issues BOTH do a command line compilation of the same file> pdfLaTeX same.tex in theory (but not practice) should produce 2 copies of same.log HOWEVER Win & Mac will show any differences starting with the first line showing version numbers etc use a good DIFF program should pick up where they truly DIFFer

Comment: If the first error line is correct it seems to be related to the use of -shell-escape in the editor which MiKTeX can use from command line so does the tex have \includes   graphics requiring write13 access @daleif are you more familiar with such configuring on Mac